# Update mysql table with a regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have table called "location" with a field "area". This field can contain various type of values. Example:

> "1.0/5.", "32.22/29.",
>   ".0/2.", "6.4/15.", "nothing" etc

I want create a regular expression that selectes only the the first number from this field and adds 1 to it.

So using the example above, the update will result in:

> "2", "33", "1", "7".

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Which part of ".0/2." is relevant to giving "1"? is it the empty string before the period, or "0/2" after the period? You just want the numbers before the period (plus one)? What is returned for "nothing"?

Comment: Why do you have this date stored like this in the first place in a relational database?

Comment: The regex am looking for should ignore the period and just select first number it comes across. Then add 1 to it.

Comment: storing it properly in the first place would solve this issue in a second.

Comment: what you mean by nothing is that null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$/e","$1+1", $input);
```

.. unless ofcourse you want to do it straight in the MySQL query

Comment: Problem solved. I used this when first inserting data into the area field. No need for an update.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Try this select query -

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(area, '/', 1), 0) + 1 FROM location
```

Then rewrite it to UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
1 + CAST(LEFT(area, LOCATE('/', area) - 1 ) AS SIGNED INTEGER)
```

or

```
1 + CAST(LEFT(area, LOCATE('/', area) - 1 ) AS DECIMAL)
```

Both will return same result (integer).

---

@jamester: Did you try?:

```
SELECT 1 + CAST(LEFT(area, LOCATE('/', area) - 1 ) AS DECIMAL)
       AS result
FROM location
```

Comment: Hi ypercube. This query is alien to me, I want to use if it gets the job done but I seem to get mysql syntax error.

Comment: It may get syntax error due to `"nothing"` or other similar values in your field.

Comment: I edited the field with just numbers and am afraid the syntax error still persists.

Comment: @jamester: Yes, it needs `SIGNED` or `SIGNED INTEGER`, i was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that. Not sure what to do with "signed". Sorry for been such newbie.

Comment: I still get the syntax error ypercube. Maybe there is something wrong with my table. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: +1 first time i am checking these functions cast,left,locate.. Query works fine

Comment: @jamester: Devart's solution is better, he's using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, instead of my `LEFT()` and `LOCATE()` combination. Also uses an implied (by the +1 addition) Cast. You actually don't need the `CAST(` and `AS DECIMAL)` parts.